# Building Regex pattern to eventually pick the desired text from the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm fetching some text-data from a TextArea in my app's UI.
The eventual goal is to recognize a pre-determined format/pattern of text form this TextArea's entire data. (I'll be further using such filtered out text, if any, to further process the Employee IDs from such text)

The valid patterns are:

1. EMP {and any valid ID here}. For e.g. EMP 1234
2. A URL with this fixed pattern: http://emps/{id} For e.g. http://emps/1234

I'll be searching for such pattern text from the source data.

Here's a bunch of regex pattern and related logic I've developed so far:

```
string sourceText = "This will contain a bunch of text. Might also contain EMP 1234 and there could be a bunch of text after this pattern. There could again be EMP 4567 or http://emps/2345 We'll be extracting all such patterns. 3 in this case." 
const string regexPattern =
    "(\\bEMP(s|(id)|:|#)?\\s*?(id|#)?\\s*?(:|#)?\\s{1})(?<EMPid>(\\d{1,11}))(\\s*?(,|(and))\\s*?(?<EMPidnew>(\\d{1,11})))*";

var search = new Regex(regexPattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

MatchCollection matches = searcher.Matches(sourceText );

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    //If we reach this point it means that the sourceText contained text which matched our pattern
    // From this point I'll be extracting the ID and process it further
}
```

The REGEX is not case-sensitive, which is intended.
The REGEX which I've developed so far, by taking syntax references from some websites, correctly handles my first pattern i.e. of:

- EMP {and any valid ID here}. For e.g. EMP 1234

But now I'm not sure how I can modify my existing Regex pattern or add upon to the existing to proceed further for my second requirement i.e.
A URL with this fixed pattern:

- http://emps/{id} For e.g. http://emps/1234

Comment: You could either use a positive lookahead asserting the occurrence of the pattern, or if the url should always be before or after it you could match it.

Comment: Your pattern with the usages of the `*` *zero or more* will cause significant backtrackings while processing text; to avoid don't use the `*` and instead use `+` *one or more*. If you are using the `*` to show abiguity between different internal patterns, try using the `|` instead of two separate `*`.

Comment: Do the ids always track from the end? Could there be text after the number? Can you provide more examples which show the intended conditions to be seen. ?

Comment: @ΩmegaMan, IDs will only be numbers. There could be additional text after the intended pattern. I've updated the sourceText  variable value in my code sample.

Comment: Perhaps use 2 named capturing groups `\b(?:EMP(?:id|[s:#])?\s+(?<EMPid>\d{1,11})|(?<EMPurl>https?://emps/\d+))(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/CtBiWX/1

Comment: I'm not seeing why asp.net is involved, unless you are doing this in front end javascript regex. But your example is all backend .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten your pattern a bit and make use of an alternation matching either one of the patterns.

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `EMP` Match literally
  - `(?:id|[s:#])?` Optionally match either id or one of `s` `:` or `#`
  - `\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars
  - `(?<EMPid>\d{1,11})` Named group *EMPid*, match 1-11 digits
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<EMPurl>https?://emps/\d+)` Named group *EMPurl* Match the url pattern
- `)` Close non capture group
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not a non whitespace char (whitespace boundary on the right)

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3aEMP%28%3f%3aid%7c%5bs%3a%23%5d%29%3f%5cs%2b%28%3f%3cEMPid%3e%5cd%7b1%2c11%7d%29%7c%28%3f%3cEMPurl%3ehttps%3f%3a%2f%2femps%2f%5cd%2b%29%29%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=This+will+contain+a+bunch+of+text.+Might+also+contain+EMP+1234+and+there+could+be+a+bunch+of+text+after+this+pattern.+There+could+again+be+EMP+4567+or+http%3a%2f%2femps%2f2345+We%27ll+be+extracting+all+such+patterns.+3+in+this+case.) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Xqumme)

*Example code*

```
string sourceText = "This will contain a bunch of text. Might also contain EMP 1234 and there could be a bunch of text after this pattern. There could again be EMP 4567 or http://emps/2345 We'll be extracting all such patterns. 3 in this case.";
const string regexPattern = @"\b(?:EMP(?:id|[s:#])?\s+(?<EMPid>\d{1,11})|(?<EMPurl>https?://emps/\d+))(?!\S)";
var search = new Regex(regexPattern , RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = search.Matches(sourceText);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value.ToString());
}
```

*Output*

```
EMP 1234
EMP 4567
http://emps/2345
```

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird.
I've tweaked and utilized the URL part of your regex a bit as per my need and using it further:
(http(s)?://emps/(\\d{1,11}))

The parenthesis after 'emps/' will help me to get the ID as a segregated value in MatchCollection.

Answer (score 1):

> The valid patterns are:
>
> 1. EMP {and any valid ID here}. For e.g. EMP 1234
> 2. A URL with this fixed pattern: http://emps/{id} For e.g. http://emps/1234

Looking at your regex in the code shows you want to go *way* beyond what you are saying in the quote. For regex I would just use:

```
(https?://emps/|\bEMP\b\s*)(?<EMPid>\d{1,11})
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I see a simple match on *consecutive* digits (two or more) will do the job of `\d{2,}`.

Using your example, here is what is capture in 3 separate matches (*in gold*):

[image: Three Matches on \d{2,}]

Of course you can improve the logic by knowing that at minimum an employee number has 4 digits so use `\d{4,}`.

Do they start with a specific number, say 9?, then add that such as `9\d{3,}`.

---

Need the prefix of `Emp` or whether it is a URL? Then build from this pattern of `(EMP\s|/)` where we look for emp or a forward slash of a URL. Such as `((EMP\s|/)\d{2,})`

[image]

---

The point here is that you can build upon basic principles to find the match. If the whole URL is needed, then add to the building blocks provided above.